# Minkowski sum of convex sets in the plane which are not polygons

Tags: convex-analysis, polygons

Can the Minkowski sum of two convex sets in the plane which are not polygons be a polygon? 
Explicitly my convex set is of the form

$
C= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x,y \geq 0 \text{ , } \sqrt{y}+\sqrt{x} \geq 1 \text{ and } y \leq 1-x\}
$

I am interested in knowing if there is a convex set C' such that the Minkowski sum

$C + C' = P$

where

$
P = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x,y \geq 0 \text{ and } 1/2 \leq x+y \leq 1 \}.
$
Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

The Minkowsky sum of two convex sets is a compact polygon only if the two summands are compact polygons.

Consider first the case that $C,C'$ are compact.
A compact convex set is a polygon if and only if there are only finitely many points that can be obtained as intersection of a line with $C$.
Let $c\in  C$ and $\ell$ a line such that $\ell\cap C=\{c\}$.
A line parallel to $\ell$ then intersects $C'$ in a segment $[c_1',c_2']$ of its boundary (where possibly $c_1'=c_2'$). 
Then  $[c+c_1',c+c_2']$ is part of the boundary of $P$ parallel to $\ell$.
Let the preceeding edge of $P$ be $[a,c+c_1']$ and the next edge be $[c+c_2',b]$
Then the lines parallel to these through $c$ bound $C$.
The exterior angle at $c$ is at least as big as the smallest exterior angle of $P$. We conclude that there can be at most finitely many such points $c$. Thus $C$ is a polygon. By the same argument,  $C'$ is a polygon.

The details of what happens when $C,C'$ are not assume closed (they must of course still be bounded) are left as an exercise. At least it is immediately  clear that $\overline C$ and $\overline{C'}$ are polygons.